# SUMIFS in VBA using named ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with a component of a VBA function.
I need to use SUMIFS to sum values from a dataset with named ranges.
I really can't see where I am going wrong but I suspect it is something to do with the named ranges.

Variables:

- ACT = an actual results flag - if "ACT" then sum a certain range, else sum data from a range of sheets ("SUMSheets")
- ML = Month lookup - JAN, FEB etc - this is the defined sum range
- VER = Version lookup value - could be ACT21 or ACT22 etc - this looks up against the named range VERSION
- AC = account number (a string) lookup value - this looks up against the ACCT named range

Named ranges:

- VERSION - the named range that VER looks up against (i.e. Data!$F$2:$F$1048576)
- ACCT - account number named range that AC looks up against (similar to VERSION)
- SUMSheets - used in the else portion of the code and defines the names of the sheets to look up (e.g. INPUT, COSTS and SALES but could be numerous sheets)

Code that I have thus far is below.
Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
Function NewfTBCalc(ACT As String, ML As String, VER As String, AC As String) As Double

Dim RangeName As String
Dim SumRange As String
Dim CalcValue As Double

If ACT = "ACT" Then
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        CalcValue = .SumIfs(.indirect(ML), Range("VERSION"), VER, Range("ACCT"), AC)
    End With
Else  
    With Application.worksheetfuction
        RangeName = "'" & SUMSheets & "'!a:a"
        
        SumRange = "'" & SUMSheets & "'!" & .Substitute(.Address(1, .Column(), 4), "1", "") & ":" & .Substitute(.Address(1, .Column(), 4), "1", "")
        
        CalcValue = .SumProduct(.SumIf(.indirect(RangeName), AC, SumRange))
    
    End With
End If

NewfTBCalc = CalcValue

End Function
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?  Is the result `#N/A` or are you getting an unexpected number?  Did you pick your formula from initiating a worksheet function that provided the correct output?  I can see some issues where we don't have the content/dimensions of the named ranges, which may lead to issues.

Comment: Also, you've verified that all of the named ranges are identical row/column counts?  E.g., `if .range("Version").rows.count = .range("acct").rows.count and .range("acct").rows.count = .range(ml).rows.count then`... as i wrote that, you have `indirect(ML)`, where you would want `Range(ML)`.

Comment: Typo - `Application.worksheetfuction`

Comment: There's no `WorkSheetFunction.Indirect` - you can review the list of worksheet functions available to VBA here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/list-of-worksheet-functions-available-to-visual-basic

Comment: Instead of (eg) `.indirect(RangeName)` you can use `Range(RangeName)`

Comment: Thank you for all your input - this is an amazing community - my issue is solved! To answer the questions: Cyril the error I was getting was #VALUE. Cyril and Tim - replacing .indirect with Range solved the issue - thank you so much

Comment: Sorry - another issue - with the "else" portion - returns #VALUE! error - the purpose of this section is to cycle through a series of sheets (defined in SUMSheets) and sum the values based on the AC (account) value and dynamically shift sum columns as the formulas changes columns